# antecedent - Most of the children, who ranged

Tags: relative-pronouns

> Most of the children, who ranged in age from 4 to 8, chose to wait.

Which is an antecedent in this sentence, "most of the children" or "the children"?

Comment: The antecedent is "most of the children".

Comment: @BillJ Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The antecedent is "most of the children".

Whether this implies that some of the children were outside of the range 4-8, and if  so what they chose to do is ambiguous.

In the absence of further context, I would assume that all the children were all aged 4-8, and most of them chose to wait (but a minority chose not to wait)